# How to find fundamental matrix based on other fundamental matrix and camera movement?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I am trying to speed up some multi-camera system that relies on calculation of fundamental matrices between each camera pair.

Please notice the following is pseudocode. `@` means matrix multiplication, `|` means concatenation.

I have code to calculate `F` for each pair `calculate_f(camera_matrix1_3x4, camera_matrix1_3x4)`, and the naiive solution is

```
for c1 in cameras:
    for c2 in cameras:
        if c1 != c2:
            f = calculate_f(c1.proj_matrix, c2.proj_matrix)
```

This is slow, and I would like to speed it up. I have ~5000 cameras.

---

I have pre calculated all rotations and translations  (in world coordinates) between every pair of cameras, and internal parameters `k`, such that  for each camera `c`, it holds that `c.matrix = c.k @ (c.rot | c.t)`

Can I use the parameters `r, t` to help speed up following calculations for `F`?

---

In mathematical form, for 3 different cameras `c1`, `c2`, `c3` I have

`f12=(c1.proj_matrix, c2.proj_matrix)`, and I want `f23=(c2.proj_matrix, c3.proj_matrix)`, `f13=(c1.proj_matrix, c3.proj_matrix)` with some function `f23, f13 = fast_f(f12, c1.r, c1.t, c2.r, c2.t, c3.r, c3.t)`?

---

A working function for calculating the fundamental matrix in numpy:

```
def fundamental_3x3_from_projections(p_left_3x4: np.array, p_right__3x4: np.array) -> np.array:
    # The following is based on OpenCv-contrib's c++ implementation.
    # see https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/sfm/src/fundamental.cpp#L109
    # see https://sourishghosh.com/2016/fundamental-matrix-from-camera-matrices/
    # see https://answers.opencv.org/question/131017/how-do-i-compute-the-fundamental-matrix-from-2-projection-matrices/
    f_3x3 = np.zeros((3, 3))
    p1, p2 = p_left_3x4, p_right__3x4

    x = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float)
    x[0, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[1, :], p1[2, :]])
    x[1, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[2, :], p1[0, :]])
    x[2, :, :] = np.vstack([p1[0, :], p1[1, :]])

    y = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float)
    y[0, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[1, :], p2[2, :]])
    y[1, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[2, :], p2[0, :]])
    y[2, :, :] = np.vstack([p2[0, :], p2[1, :]])

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            xy = np.vstack([x[j, :], y[i, :]])
            f_3x3[i, j] = np.linalg.det(xy)

    return f_3x3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numpy is clearly not optimized for working on small matrices**. The parsing of CPython input objects, internal checks and function calls introduce a significant overhead which is far bigger than the execution time need to perform the actual computation. Not to mention the creation of *many temporary arrays* is also expensive. One solution to solve this problem is to **use Numba or Cython**.

Moreover, the computation of the determinant can be optimized a lot since you know the exact size of the matrix and a part of the matrix does not always change. Indeed, using a **basic algebraic expression for the 4x4 determinant** help compilers to optimize a lot the overall computation thanks to the [common sub-expression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (not performed by the CPython interpreter) and the removal of complex loops/conditionals in `np.linalg.det`.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('float64(float64[:,::1])')
def det_4x4(mat):
    a, b, c, d = mat[0,0], mat[0,1], mat[0,2], mat[0,3]
    e, f, g, h = mat[1,0], mat[1,1], mat[1,2], mat[1,3]
    i, j, k, l = mat[2,0], mat[2,1], mat[2,2], mat[2,3]
    m, n, o, p = mat[3,0], mat[3,1], mat[3,2], mat[3,3]
    return a * (f * (k*p - l*o) + g * (l*n - j*p) + h * (j*o - k*n)) + \
            b * (e * (l*o - k*p) + g * (i*p - l*m) + h * (k*m - i*o)) + \
            c * (e * (j*p - l*n) + f * (l*m - i*p) + h * (i*n - j*m)) + \
            d * (e * (k*n - j*o) + f * (i*o - k*m) + g * (j*m - i*n))

@nb.njit('float64[:,::1](float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])')
def fundamental_3x3_from_projections(p_left_3x4, p_right_3x4):
    f_3x3 = np.empty((3, 3))
    p1, p2 = p_left_3x4, p_right_3x4

    x = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float64)
    x[0, 0, :] = p1[1, :]
    x[0, 1, :] = p1[2, :]
    x[1, 0, :] = p1[2, :]
    x[1, 1, :] = p1[0, :]
    x[2, 0, :] = p1[0, :]
    x[2, 1, :] = p1[1, :]

    y = np.empty((3, 2, 4), dtype=np.float64)
    y[0, 0, :] = p2[1, :]
    y[0, 1, :] = p2[2, :]
    y[1, 0, :] = p2[2, :]
    y[1, 1, :] = p2[0, :]
    y[2, 0, :] = p2[0, :]
    y[2, 1, :] = p2[1, :]

    xy = np.empty((4, 4), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(3):
        xy[2:4, :] = y[i, :, :]
        for j in range(3):
            xy[0:2, :] = x[j, :, :]
            f_3x3[i, j] = det_4x4(xy)

    return f_3x3
```

This is **130 times faster** on my machine (85.6 us VS 0.66 us).

You can speed up the process even more by a factor of two if the applied function is **commutative** (ie. `f(c1, c2) == f(c2, c1)`). If so, you could **compute only the upper part**. It turns out that your function have some interesting property since `f(c1, c2) == f(c2, c1).T` appear to be always true. Another possible optimization is to run the loop in **parallel**.

With all these optimizations, the resulting program should be about *3 order of magnitude faster*.

---

### Analysis of the accuracy of the approach

The precision provided appear to be similar than the original one. Regarding the input matrix, results are sometime more accurate and sometimes less accurate than the Numpy method. This is specifically due to the computation of the *determinant*. With 24-digit decimals, there is no visible error compared to the [reliable result of Wolphram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%28%7B%7B42%2C-6248%2C4060%2C845%7D%2C+++++%7B-0.00992%2C-0.704%2C-0.71173298417%2C300.532%7D%2C+++++%7B-8.94274%2C-7554.39%2C604.57%2C706282%7D%2C+++++%7B-0.0132%2C-0.2757%2C-0.961%2C247.65%7D%7D%29). This show that the method is correct, results as not the same due to numerical stability details. Here is the code used to test the accuracy of the methods:

```py
# Imports

from decimal import Decimal
import numba as nb

# Definitions

def det_4x4(mat):
    a, b, c, d = mat[0,0], mat[0,1], mat[0,2], mat[0,3]
    e, f, g, h = mat[1,0], mat[1,1], mat[1,2], mat[1,3]
    i, j, k, l = mat[2,0], mat[2,1], mat[2,2], mat[2,3]
    m, n, o, p = mat[3,0], mat[3,1], mat[3,2], mat[3,3]
    return a * (f * (k*p - l*o) + g * (l*n - j*p) + h * (j*o - k*n)) + \
            b * (e * (l*o - k*p) + g * (i*p - l*m) + h * (k*m - i*o)) + \
            c * (e * (j*p - l*n) + f * (l*m - i*p) + h * (i*n - j*m)) + \
            d * (e * (k*n - j*o) + f * (i*o - k*m) + g * (j*m - i*n))

@nb.njit('float64(float64[:,::1])')
def det_4x4_numba(mat):
    a, b, c, d = mat[0,0], mat[0,1], mat[0,2], mat[0,3]
    e, f, g, h = mat[1,0], mat[1,1], mat[1,2], mat[1,3]
    i, j, k, l = mat[2,0], mat[2,1], mat[2,2], mat[2,3]
    m, n, o, p = mat[3,0], mat[3,1], mat[3,2], mat[3,3]
    return a * (f * (k*p - l*o) + g * (l*n - j*p) + h * (j*o - k*n)) + \
            b * (e * (l*o - k*p) + g * (i*p - l*m) + h * (k*m - i*o)) + \
            c * (e * (j*p - l*n) + f * (l*m - i*p) + h * (i*n - j*m)) + \
            d * (e * (k*n - j*o) + f * (i*o - k*m) + g * (j*m - i*n))


# Example matrix

precise_xy = np.array(
     [[Decimal('42'),Decimal('-6248'),Decimal('4060'),Decimal('845')],
      [Decimal('-0.00992'),Decimal('-0.704'),Decimal('-0.71173298417'),Decimal('300.532')],
      [Decimal('-8.94274'),Decimal('-7554.39'),Decimal('604.57'),Decimal('706282')],
      [Decimal('-0.0132'),Decimal('-0.2757'),Decimal('-0.961'),Decimal('247.65')]]
)

xy = precise_xy.astype(np.float64)

res_numpy = Decimal(np.linalg.det(xy))
res_numba = Decimal(det_4x4_numba(xy))
res_precise = det_4x4(precise_xy)

# The Wolphram Alpha expression used is:
# det({{42,-6248,4060,845},
#     {-0.00992,-0.704,-0.71173298417,300.532},
#     {-8.94274,-7554.39,604.57,706282},
#     {-0.0132,-0.2757,-0.961,247.65}})
res_wolframalpha = Decimal('-323312.2164828991329828243')

# The result got from Wolfram-Alpha have a 25-digit precision
# and is exactly the same than the one of det_4x4 using 24-digit decimals.
assert res_precise == res_wolframalpha

print(abs((res_numpy-res_precise)/res_precise))  # 1.7E-14
print(abs((res_numba-res_precise)/res_precise))  # 3.1E-14
# => Similar relative error (Numba slightly less accurate
#    but both are not close to the 1e-16 relative epsilon)
```

Comment: Thanks for this very elaborate answer! I am running your code as is, and seeing a very large diff in the `[2,2]` coordinate of the output. Any idea?

Comment: example input: `[[ 7.28674805e+03 -1.40053589e+03 -1.53241333e+03 -4.36604656e+05], [ 6.98848495e+01 -6.24813477e+03  4.06058203e+03  8.45075500e+05], [-9.92400013e-03 -7.04365015e-01 -7.11732984e-01  3.00532959e+02]]` and `[[ 7.39617090e+03 -5.67730774e+02 -2.02145935e+03  8.72439844e+04], [-8.94274139e+00 -7.55439990e+03  6.04575195e+02  7.06282625e+05], [-1.32719995e-02 -2.75792003e-01 -9.61835027e-01  2.47654922e+02]]`. Output diff: `[[-6.05359674e-08  7.62939453e-06 -1.09375000e-01], [ 2.38418579e-07 -3.33786011e-06 -9.76562500e-02], [-4.68750000e-02  5.07812500e-02 -1.76000000e+02]]`

Comment: Looking a bit deeper, the `det_4x4` returns a (very) different result than `np.linalg.det`.

Comment: Indeed. However, this seems to be due to the high values returned by the determinant. The relative difference is very small: about 5e-15 (using the formula `np.max(np.abs(real-ref)/ref)`). This is a bit more than the minimum error of 1e-16 due to the rounding of 64-bit floats. This difference comes from the different algorithm used to compute the determinant. The proposed one use the basic formula while Numpy certainly use a Gauss-Jordan elimination. I do not know which one is the most accurate yet. I will check. Both are relatively good.

Comment: Using 28-digit precision floating-point numbers with the `Decimal` package, I found that **the `det_4x4` method is slightly more accurate than the Numpy one**. The proposed method as a relative error of 5.8e-16 while the one of Numpy 4.8e-15. This explains the difference between the two. Numpy uses a LU factorization in the log space. I think the log-space conversion introduces a small higher inaccuracy in this case. However, I think the method they use is numerically stable for bigger matrices while still being quite efficient (the basic method is too expensive for bigger matrices).

Comment: You can find the code of the Numpy `det` function [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src#L1148).

Comment: Why is relative error the correct measurement here?

Comment: Regarding the error calculation - What do you refer to as `real`?

Comment: I added the code to analyze the accuracy of the approach. I used another input matrix (so to be able to compare results with Wolfram Alpha) and results are different. Thus, finally, I am not sure one method is more accurate than the other for all matrices... Both are relatively good regarding the target matrix. The absolute error should not be used for big numbers because floating point numbers are encoded to the form `+/- mantissa * 2**exp` where `mantissa` is a *normalized* number between 0 and 1 with a fixed number of binary digits and `exp` is a (bounded) integer.

Comment: An example of absolute difference between two big numbers is: `int(1234567891011121314151617181920.)-1234567891011121314151617181920`. The result is `-52638859835616` which is huge. However the relative difference is very small and the result is due to the rounding of the 64-bit float that cannot represent accurately the 31 decimal digit integer in a [52-bit mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Floating point numbers are relative numbers (based on their exponent). Thus, the relative error is often a good choice (but it strongly depends of the goal).

Comment: By the way, why do you consider WolframAlpha's result more reliable than that of numpy's?

Comment: @Gulzar Because WolframAlpha uses an higher precision resulting most of the time in an higher accuracy. It also provides a way to increase the precision manually. The main reason here is simply to get another source of result that does not comes from my code (which can contain mistakes) nor the one of Numpy confirming the high accuracy of the Decimal-based method. The fact that WolframAlpha and Decimal-based method gives the same 25-digit precision result show that they are certainly both correct and accurate. Note that Numpy makes some trade-off between accuracy and performance (eg. `np.sum`)